# Getting count of number of hosts per log message

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table structure is:

```
[Event Time]
[Log Message] 
[Hostname] 
[Client]
```

Is it possible for me to get the count of the number of unique hosts per log message?

I can get the total count per log message per client using the below, but im trying to get the number of unique hosts per log message

```
Select sub.* 
From (SELECT Count([Event Time]) AS test
             ,[Log Message]
             ,[Client]
      FROM   [Severe_logs].[dbo].[Severe_logs]
      Group BY [Client], [Log Message]
     )sub
WHERE sub.test > 25
ORDER BY test DESC
```

the output i would like is

```
Count - Log Message - Client
5        log x         Client1
6        log x         Client 2
```

How would i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please, tag your RDBMS.

Comment: RDBMS added, thanks.

Comment: Count(hostname) over (partition by [Log message] order by Client) should do the trick ... it's just out from the head, maybe some changes are needed, if you add some input data, we could figure it out faster ... but check OVER clauses with partition by .... or just give it a shot with count (distinct [Log Message])

Comment: if you just want to count the DISTINCT Clients, you could use Count(DISTINCT [Client]) - or am i misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a count distinct

```
Select sub.* 
From (SELECT Count(distinct hostname) AS test
             ,[Log Message]
             ,[Client]
      FROM   [Severe_logs].[dbo].[Severe_logs]
      Group BY [Client], [Log Message]
     )sub
WHERE sub.test > 25
ORDER BY test DESC
```

Comment: This looks good, gonna do some checks before i mark as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, is there a way i could get the same results without using Count(distinct hostname) as the powershell module I'm trying to use does not like distinct within the count

Comment: count(distinct ... ) is a sql - server common  statement ..  what's the problem ??  .. you shoul post a new question related  to this .. need .. eventually comment me the link